# Logarithm is not defined on $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-functions

Consider the principal branch of logarithm in its polar form $$f(z)=\ln r+i\theta$$ If we take as domain $G=\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$ then obviously $\theta$ is not a continuous function of $z$ as we approach the negative real axis. However, one can be tempted to verify the Cauchy-Riemann equations in their polar form and conclude (mistakenly) that the function is analytic since $$u=\ln r, v=\theta$$ and $$u_r=\frac{1}{r}, v_\theta=1$$
Which detail is the person overlooking while doing so?

Edit: I have seen proofs of why logarithm is analytic on $\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0]$ and it involves doing exactly what I did above; however, the proofs do not reflect why we need such a domain.

Comment: What appens when you try to compute $v_\theta$ at a point where $v$ is discontinuous?

Comment: @GEdgar My confusion arises from the fact that $v=\theta$ itself. When I take partials will it not be $1$ by definition?

Comment: You can't render $v_\theta$ on the cut where $v$ is discontinuous.

Comment: OK: the function $\theta$ is not defined on the complex plane since $\theta \ne \theta + 2\pi$.  However it is defined on a "Riemann surface" and analytic there.

Comment: @GEdgar I'm afraid I don't fully understand what you said and how it answers my question

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem is with multivalued functions.

In essence, the logarithm takes $z= re^{i\theta}\neq 0$ and gives the set $$\left\{\ln(r) +i\left( \theta + 2k\pi\right)\mid k\in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$$
as the exponential of any of them is $z$.

Once we have set up that $-\pi <\theta \leq \pi$ i.e. $z\in \mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty, 0]$ we have a way to choose a member of the above list and make a (univalued) function that happens to be given by the expression $\ln(r) +i\theta$.

Let's see in an example how it works. I'll take the limit $\lim\limits_{z\to -1}\log(z)$ for two determinations of the logarithm.

First we fix the principal branch $-\pi <\theta \leq \pi$. Take $z = -1 + it$ then

$$\lim\limits_{t\to 0^+}\log(-1+it) = \lim\limits_{t\to 0^+} i\theta(t) =  i\pi \, \text{ and } \lim\limits_{t\to 0^-}\log(-1+it) = -i\pi $$
 Now if we select the branch $0 <\theta \leq 2\pi$ (defined on $\mathbb{C} \setminus [0,\infty)$)  we have that 
$$
\lim\limits_{z\to -1}\log(z) = i\pi.
$$

Both are given by the same expression but they differ when it comes to how $\theta$ behaves.

Comment: Actually, what I wanted to know is if there is some precaution to be taken when dealing with the polar form of the Cauchy Riemann equations? When I want to check whether a function is analytic or not I would turn to CR equations.

Comment: The only precaution would be the continuity of the argument $\theta$. Just make sure that the point doesn't go around the origin and you are good.  In this case there exists a well defined determination of the argument.

Comment: Be careful that the CR equations only imply that the function is analytic once you have that it is differentiable as a real map. For instance the principal branch of the logarithm is not continuous at the negative real axis, hence not differentiable.

Comment: This also confused me since the existence of continuous partials along with CR equations imply differentiability. When I look at partials with respect to $\theta$ and $r$ I find that they are indeed continuous.

Comment: @HritRoy The caution is that you need continuity in the underlying plane which means periodicity in $\theta$.